# Cursor/Touchpad lag while using Battery Power in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04, mouse, touchpad, battery, cursor

Long time reader, first time caller. I'm experiencing a cursor lag in Ubuntu 22.04 but only when plugged into battery power. Once unplugged, the cursor moves at the expected rate. Also of note is that once I unplug from battery power, it takes up to a minute before the computer registers the disconnect (makes the disconnect noise and removes the charging icon in the top corner). I'm using an Asus Zenbook 14 and would appreciate any advice. Thanks!